# Can we obfuscate annotations in java using dex2jar tool or any other way?

Tags: java, android, obfuscation, aspectj

I am building a project with the help of AspectJ to intercept the method in Android.
When I build the jar file of code i created it creates compiled syntax of each pointcut i applied on the methods as like bellow:

Code before obfuscation:

```
 @After(value="(execution(* android.app.Activity.onCreate(..)) && (target(obj) && within(com.snapdeal.ui.activity.MainActivity)))", argNames="obj")
      public void ajc$after$demo_Common_Aspects$1$dcc8d2c5(Object obj)
      {
        .
        .
        .
      }
```

When I obfuscate this method using dex2jar tool it only changes the name of method from

```
ajc$after$demo_Common_Aspects$19$a6eef354
```

to the string I used to obfuscate `pkt1` but Anotation i.e. line above the method definition does not change which shows details of method interception.

Code after obfuscation:

```
 @After(value="(execution(* android.app.Activity.onCreate(..)) && (target(obj) && within(com.snapdeal.ui.activity.MainActivity)))", argNames="obj")
  public void pkt1(Object obj)
  {
      .
      .
      .
   }
```

Uptil now what i know is that we can obfuscate the names of Classes,methods and variables.
But I want to obfuscate this line :

```
@After(value="(execution(* android.app.Activity.onCreate(..)) && (target(obj) && within(com.snapdeal.ui.activity.MainActivity)))", argNames="obj")
```

So my Quitions are :

1. Can we obfuscate annotations ? If yes how?
2. How can we obfuscate the local variables of some method?

Answer (score 1):

> Can we obfuscate annotations ? If yes how?

Theoretically yes.  But if you did, the AspectJ annotation inspection code would not recognize them.  Hence, it would be a bad idea.

> How can we obfuscate the local variables of some method?

It is moot.  The names of local variables are not included in the source bytecode file in the first place.

Method parameter names are another matter though.  But in your example, the names of the parameters are used by the annotation processor.  If the obfuscator changed them without also changing the annotation parameters that referred to them, the processor would fail.

---

In theory, you could have an obfuscator + modified AspectJ processor that did this.  However, there is no indication that (for example) "proguard" or "dexguard" can do this.

Answer (score 1):

Once the weaving has been done (I presume you are doing compile time weaving?) you could actually just strip out the annotations. They were only needed during the matching/weaving stage, they are not typically consulted again (e.g. at runtime). You could write a simple Asm visitor that stripped out any in the org.aspectj package.

Answer (score 0):

You could work around the problem of annotation obfuscation (sounds like a pretty frail thing to me) by using native AspectJ syntax for your aspects. Maybe that is more promising, but I have not tried.

*BTW, being over-paranoid concerning obfuscation is usually not worth the trouble. Java noobs will not try to decompile your apps and real Java wizards will be able to decompile major parts of it anyway. But that is kind of off topic, sorry I could not resist.*